# Elastic search stucks during its initialization

Tags: java, elasticsearch

When I tried to up the Elastic search, it gets hanged(shown in below image).It takes more than 15 minutes to start normally.  However when I tried the same setup on different machines elastic search server gets up in 5 to 10 seconds and it worked fine (Except 3,those 3 machines also showed same problem). What would be the possible cause for this?
Due to this problem I got `org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available` exception from java.
Note: My elasticSearch is working as standalone node on each m/c.

[image]

Comment: Might be connected to ES's automatic cluster nodes discovery. Try to disable it (use `unicast` with empty server list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution [here](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Elasticsearch-0-19-8-doesn-t-initialize-hangs-td4020306.html#a4020307).

Probable solutions:

- It's always a good idea to install a current Java JRE to enjoy resolved bugs.
- Check if your os network settings (routes, gateway) and mount points are configured correctly.
- Remove sigar libraries in order to avoid sigar monitoring hangs
- From the logs ES seems to hang before the node is going to initialize plugins, so remove all ES plugins, check the classpath (the lib directory is loaded with *) and remove unwanted/duplicate jars